# Qemu/KVM Postcopy migration fails in hirsute / v5.11 kernels (solved)

Tags: kernel, kvm-virtualization, qemu

[postcopy migration](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/PostCopyLiveMigration) isn't the default but can in some cases be very useful

With Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute kernel being v5.11 postcopy migration will fail like:

```
virsh migrate --unsafe --live --postcopy --postcopy-after-precopy kvmguest-focal-postcopy qemu+ssh://10.85.93.248/system
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'migrate-set-capabilities': Postcopy is not supported
```

Answer (score 2):

The v5.11 kernel contains the following upstream change [userfaultfd: add user-mode only option to unprivileged_userfaultfd sysctl knob](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d0d4730ac2)

This will also apply to e.g. a Focal-HWE kernel once on v5.11 or to Focal userspaces in a container under a Hirsute kernel (that is the example above).

This was done for security reasons, if you want/need to re-enable un-limited userfault handling to be able to use postcopy again you'd want/need to set the control knob to one like:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w "vm.unprivileged_userfaultfd=1"
```

I mostly wanted users to be able to find the background and solution, therefore I also documented this in bug [1926249](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1926249)